# Can not pass variables to partial (Rails5)

Tags: variables, ruby-on-rails-5, renderpartial

I got such a problem - there is a partial and I can not pass a variable there:

in partial I have;

```
<%= object.title %>
```

How I pass variables:

```
<%= render :partial => 'shared/post_preview', :locals => { :object => article } %>
```

the error I see looks like

```
**undefined local variable or method `object'**
```

Any ideas? I tried already everything seems...

also tried:

```
  <%= render :partial => 'shared/post_preview', :object => article %>
  <%= render 'shared/post_preview', :object => article %>
  <%= render :partial => 'shared/post_preview', :object => article %>
```

everytime i see the same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was in the commented code in the partial file. Somehow it was counted like an actual code...

```
<!--
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <%= render :partial => 'shared/post_preview' %>
    <%= render :partial => 'shared/post_preview' %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <%= render :partial => 'shared/post_preview' %>
    <%= render :partial => 'shared/post_preview' %>
  </div>
</div>
-->
```

Comment: Of course, because `<!--` is just html comment, not ruby comment, so the erb will be evaluated anyway to generate a commented html. If you want to comment the code, try with `#`, something like `<%=# render :partial => 'shared/post_preview' %>`

Answer (score 3):

**Use this:**

Assuming you have defined @article instance variable in action.

```
<%= render 'shared/post_preview', object: @article  %>
```

This must solve your problem.

Comment: No, the problem was in a commented code contained Ruby and the standard commenting working for html like <!-- --> does not work for Ruby part of code,